# Modeling Employee/ Team Leader relationship

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design, entity-relationship, data-modeling

Consider the follwing tables:

`EMP`

PK: **EMP_ID**

`PROJECT`

PK: **PROJECT_ID**

`EMP_PROJECT` ( Connection table to creat M:N relation)

PK: **EMP_ID**, **PROJECT_ID**
FK: **EMP_ID**, **PROJECT_ID**

Employee can work on many projects. Each Project can be done by many employees as well. I want to represent in my model the fact that the team ( group of employees) handling a project must have a team leader.

I thought of creating a new table `Supervision` (PK: Supervision_ID) with an attribute for the start date. But I am not sure to wich table must this table relate.

Answer (score 4):

I think the draft model will help you:
[image]